# Jenkins Multibranch using Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin not building merged branches

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I've opened this on Jenkins issue tracker, but also looking here if anyone knows.

I've just updated the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin within a multibranch pipeline to the latest version.

I'm using a webhook to send events to Jenkins from Bitbucket private instance.

My flow looks like this:

```
Branch Push -> Build
PR Open -> Build
PR Updated (via pushing code) -> Build
PR Merged into Dev -> Dev SHOULD Build, but it doesnt
```

I am seeing the hook in the pipeline events, but `dev` does not build unless I do a manual (or a timed) scan, but that defeats the purpose of build triggers.

Anyone know how to setup the plugin to build merged branches (`dev`, in my case)?

Comment: Are you really expecting an answer without providing exact details about the Jenkins and plugin versions involved?

Comment: Are you using Bitbucket Server or Bitbucket Cloud? If Server, what plugin are you using to trigger Jenkins jobs on PR events?